# Is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ countable or uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ countable or uncountable ? I have no idea on how to start. Any hint or guide will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use Cantor's diagonal argument. Assume the set of all function form $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ is countable, and derive the contradiction.

Comment: Hint: Find a bijection with the powerset. For any set $S$ and any map $f\colon S\to P(S)$, $f$ fails to be onto because it misses $\{x\in S\mid x\notin f(S)\}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Find bijection between powerset and what ?

Comment: @Idonknow ... a bijection between the poswerset of $\mathbb N$ and the set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$, cf. Asaf's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: You can think of each function as a binary representation; then use Cantor's diagonal argument to show that it can't be countable.

Set up a table like $$\begin{align}&a_{11}a_{12}a_{13}\ldots\\ &a_{21}a_{22}a_{23}\ldots\\ &a_{31}a_{32}a_{33}\ldots \end{align}$$ where each $a_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$, and use the diagonal argument with the $a_{jj}$.

Comment: What is binary representation?

Comment: You can think of the function as assigning a position, so for example, you could have $$1_10_20_30_4\ldots$$ as possible representation (the binary says that only zeroes and ones are present). Here, the subscripts represent what number mapped to that image, i.e., $1\mapsto 1$, $2\mapsto 0$, and so on.

Comment: I still don know how to proceed.

Comment: I've edited my answer for hopefully a more-clear hint.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very blur.

Comment: Idonknow, do you know how Cantor's Diagonal Argument works? Set $a_{jj}=1$ if it isn't $1$ already, otherwise set it to $0$, then you've constructed an element not in the set by definition, hence it can't be countable, otherwise you couldn't have constructed an element not in the set.

Comment: Clayton, perhaps ditch the usual table approach. @Idonknow: Suppose that $f_1,\ldots$ is a countable sequence of functions in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$, we define the function $F(n)=1-f_n(n)$. Check that $F\colon\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$, and now show that it differs from $f_1,f_2,\ldots$. If $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ was countable we could have enumerated it like that, but then $F$ would be somewhere in the list. This is impossible and therefore $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Clayton: okay , now I understand what you mean. But it seems you are not answering my original question.

Comment: @Idonknow: It shows the set cannot be countable.... Hence it is uncountable, which is exactly what you were asking.

Comment: @Clayton: ooh, I fully understand now .

Comment: @Idonknow: I'm glad! :) Hopefully it is clear now.

Answer (score 13):

**Hint:** Show that the function $F\colon\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ defined by $F(f)=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid f(n)=1\}$ is a bijection.

Use Cantor's theorem to show that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable and deduce the same on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$.

Comment: how do we show F(f) is injective ?