# Show $\mathbb{N}^{\{0,1\}}$ is uncountable with a hint

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, proof-explanation

Let $\mathbb{N}^{\{0,1\}} :=\{f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}\}$ is uncountable

I have never heard of the table approach, and all the proofs say uncountability of $\mathcal {P}(\mathbb{N})$ I have seen so far do not use the table approach. There was a hint how to do this without listing stuff in a table: [Is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ countable or uncountable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287434/is-the-set-of-all-functions-from-mathbbn-to-0-1-countable-or-uncounta?rq=1)

> Suppose that $f_1,…$  is a countable sequence of functions in
>   $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, we define the function $F(n)=1−f_n(n)$. Check
>   that $F:\mathbb{N}\to\{0,1\}$, and now show that it differs from
>   $f_1,f_2,…$. If $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$  was countable we could have
>   enumerated it like that, but then $F$  would be somewhere in the list.
>   This is impossible and therefore $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$  is uncountable.

Couple of questions:

1. Does $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} = \{f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}\}$, I maybe using conflicting notations

If that is the case, then the function $F$ makes sense

2. What does it mean by "now show that it differs from  $f_1,f_2,…$"?

Does it  mean suppose $f_k(n) = F(n)$, then $F(n) = 1 - f_k(n) = 1 - F(n)$, so $F(n) = \dfrac{1}{2}$ so this is impossible.

Comment: By definition, $A^B$ is the set of functions from $B$ to $A$, for all sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @GitGud Oh that's a terrible convention, your pre-image should come before your image. Looking at $A^B$ makes me think of $f: A \to B$

Comment: Ad 1: This is right. Ad 2: It means that $F \neq f_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. In particular $F(n) = 1-f_n(n) \neq f_n(n)$.

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows I disagree, since for finite sets, you have $|A^B| = |A|^{|B|}$.  It feels more akward to have $|A^B| = |B|^{|A|}$

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows "Before" is a relative term. You're reading from left to right. Anyway, the motivation behind the notation is this. Consider the number $2^3$. Now take a set with two members, say $\{0,1\}$ and another one with three elements, say $\{0,1,2\}$. You can prove that the set of functions from the latter to the form has exactly $8$ elements (which equals $2^3$). This is true for any choice of finite sets, hence the generalization of the notation.

Comment: As an aside, the set of functions from $\{0,1\}$ to $\Bbb N$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ and is known to be countable as it is the cartesian product of a finite number of countable sets.  On the other hand, the set of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$ are in bijection with the binary expansions of the set of real numbers between $0$ and $1$ which we know to be uncountable.  The proof for why those are uncountable is outlined already in your post.

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows You couldn't be more mistaken about the definition of $A^B.$ It's perfectly natural.